# Mapping the same list in two entities and updating the list with Spring Data

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I have 2 entities `Sell` and `Buy` each with a list of `Offer` as shown below.

My doubt is how must I map these two entities in the `Offer`. Do I have to add an attribute with a `@ManyToOne` annotation for each of them? Is my current mappings correct?

Also, when I add a new element to the Offer list, how do I update it using Spring Data?
I am using repositories with `JpaRepository` and didn't find a method to update or merge the bean.

Sell entity:

```
@Entity
public class Sell implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "sell_sequence", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sell_sequence", sequenceName = "sell_sequence", allocationSize = 1)
    private Long id;

    // other fields...

    @OneToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.REMOVE, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST })
    @JoinTable(name = "selloffer",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "sell_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "offer_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private List<Offer> offers = new ArrayList<>();

    // constructors, getters and setters...
}
```

Buy entity:

```
@Entity
public class Buy implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "buy_sequence", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "buy_sequence", sequenceName = "buy_sequence", allocationSize = 1)
    private Long id;

    // other fields...

    @OneToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.REMOVE })
    @JoinTable(name = "buyoffer",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "buy_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "offer_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private List<Offer> offers;

    // constructors, getters and setters...
}
```

And the Offer:

```
@Entity
public class Offer implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "offer_sequence", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "offer_sequence", sequenceName = "offer_sequence", allocationSize = 1)
    private Long id;

    @Column(length = 500)
    String description;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST })
    @JoinColumn(name = "bidder_id", nullable = false)
    User bidder;
}
```

Comment: Why did you use a join table on a OneToMany Reation? those should be necesary only for ManyToMany Relationships

Comment: I thought it necessary to create the intermediary tables "buyoffer" and "selloffer". Although I was not sure it was correct.

Comment: so each offer only has 1 Buy and Sell instance?

Comment: Yes, but never both at the same time. In other words, I can make one offer for a sell or a different offer for a buy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I speculate, your relationships should be OneToOne(or manyToOne withour join table), with no join table, this seems like it will solve your problem, just check the join columns in the offer class(not sure if they are correct for your case)

```
@Entity
public class Sell implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "sell_sequence", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sell_sequence", sequenceName = "sell_sequence", allocationSize = 1)
    private Long id;

    // other fields...

    @OneToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.REMOVE, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST },mappedBy = "sell")

    private List<Offer> offers = new ArrayList<>();

    // constructors, getters and setters...
}

@Entity
public class Buy implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "buy_sequence", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "buy_sequence", sequenceName = "buy_sequence", allocationSize = 1)
    private Long id;

    // other fields...

    @OneToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.REMOVE },mappedBy = "buy")
    private List<Offer> offers;

    // constructors, getters and setters...
}

@Entity
public class Offer implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "offer_sequence", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "offer_sequence", sequenceName = "offer_sequence", allocationSize = 1)
    private Long id;

    @Column(length = 500)
    String description;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST })
    @JoinColumn(name = "bidder_id", nullable = false)
    User bidder;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinTable(name = "selloffer",
        joinColumns =  @JoinColumn(name = "offer_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
        inverseJoinColumns =@JoinColumn(name = "sell_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private Sell sell;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinTable(name = "buyoffer",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "offer_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "buy_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private Buy buy;
}
```

Comment: That worked, although I changed this solution to have two different entities for the Offer, a SellOffer and a BuyOffer, so I will have two tables instead of having one with null values. Thanks.